# How to disable autocompletion for sudo ...?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, oh-my-zsh

I am new to zsh and I like it a lot, especially with oh-my-zsh plugin. I installed oh-my-zsh with its default values and can't figure out how to turn off autocompletion for specific commands, that I often use, such as:
`sudo mc` or `sudo gem update`. The thing is that I have .mc directory and .gem directory and zsh proposes corresponding autocompletions (for .mc and .gem).

Generally I would like to config zsh so that `sudo` is not considered a separate command (which it is not) with the following as a params. Is there a config for that?

Comment: I had posted a answer, but, this didn't worked as expected. Removed ^^

Comment: Do you want to _disable_ autocompletion, or actually have autocompletion still work for the command run under sudo, as if the word `sudo` weren't there?

Comment: Sorry, everyone. I have actually asked a wrong question. I meant autocorrection of spelling.

Comment: Then please start a new question.  Your description still mentions your original problem in parts, and is now very unclear.  Not to mention uther has spent time answering the question you originally asked.

Comment: I flagged the question for deletion and understand the caused confusion. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @AlexeiDanchenkov Well, if there's a right answer we might as well leave it; I just changed it back to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring directory patterns is fairly painless. You can add the following to your `~/.zshrc`.

The first line ignores `.mc` and `.gem` patterns after issuing `cd [TAB]`. The next line ignores them after issuing `sudo [TAB]`.

```
zstyle ':completion:*:cd:*' ignored-patterns '(*/)#.mc' '(*/)#.gem'
zstyle ':completion:*:sudo:*' ignored-patterns '(*/)#.mc' '(*/)#.gem'
```